# Receive message request via Whatsapp with webhook

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

I need to create a webhook to respond to a request coming from Whatsapp, the first time I'm making this response and I'm taking a beating to receive this data.

I created the webhook route on the server pointing to my computer, and I'm using ngrok to test it.

[image]

Doing a request using get the controller responds

[image]

[image]

I have some doubts about to receive the data from Whatsapp.

Which verbose do I use to get the data from Whatsapp?

How can I get these data?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can be useful. I pointed the webhook to the POST inside my controller.

[image]

Inside the controller you handle the data received according to your solution. I sent a console.log for testing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! I know it's not the same issue, but I'm investigating how to send more than one message with the help of the whatsapp api in nodejs, I dare to ask because I read that it handles the whatsapp webhook issue